# How can you take a table and turn it into a workflow graph

Tags: architecture

I have a set of tables that defines the workflow. 
Say possible states are New, InProgress, Cancelled, Complete. I have a worfklow steps table that defines which new state the current state goes to using a user response such as approve, decline, cancel, complete.

My question is how would you turn this data into a flow chart graph, using basically any programming language.

```
WorkflowStatesTable
ID | Description
1 | New
2 | InProgress
3 | Complete
4 | Cancelled


WorkflowStepsTable
UniqueID | CurrentWorkflowState | Response | NewWorkflowState
 1           1(New)               "Work"         2(InProgress)
 2           1(New)               "Cancel"       4(Cancelled)
 3           1(New)               "Complete"     3(Complete)
 4           2(InProgress)        "Complete"     3(Complete
 5           2(InProgress)        "Cancel"       4(Cancel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) is a great tool for generating flow charts from textual data.

Go to the [mermaid online editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/) and enter this

```
graph TD
    New --> |Work| InProgress
    New --> |Complete| Complete
    InProgress --> |Complete| Complete
    InProgress --> |Cancel| Cancelled
    New --> |Cancel| Cancelled
```

and you'll get something like this

[image]

How you get from your data to the graph data is left as an exercise.

Comment: I had no idea this tool existed. Thank you very much.